# [Solved - 3D movement on X and Y with mesh colliders

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision

I am working on an Asteroids clone in 3D with top-down camera. This setup is static and will not change (so no, I do not want to transform the project to 2D game instead).

This means that I need to limit all movement to X and Y axis. I created movement for both asteroids and player and everything worked fine. All movements are done using `AddForce` on respective `RigidBody` components.

The problem is then I start dealing with collisions. I use `Mesh Collider` components to get a nice and precise "touch reaction". The problem is that when collision like this occurs, the new movement vector has Z value different from 0. This is a problem as the object will start moving on Z axis.

**What have I tried:**

1. Freezing constraints on RigidBody
2. Manully reseting Z in `Update` function

The first solution (freezing constraints) did not work and neither did the second one (moreover, the second one seems quite messy)

**So the question is**

What would be the optimal way to force physics-based movement only to X and Y axis while using precise collision with `Mesh Colliders`?

[image]

Comment: are you sure you used the position restriction correctly? You can check to set the restrictions with a vector as in the documentation.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePosition.html to see how its done. If not please share the code or a screenshot of the rigidbody restrictions you tried in the editor

Comment: I managed to work with your advice and solved the issue. I am not sure if I can mark your comment as accepted answer though so I just adjusted the original post. Thank you!

Comment: I posted it as the answer. You can check it as accepted if you consider so ;) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you sure you used the position restriction correctly? You can check to set the restrictions with a vector as in the documentation. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePosition.html
to see how its done. If not please share the code or a screenshot of the rigidbody restrictions you tried in the editor